# drupal and status.net sso

Tags: drupal, single-sign-on, statusnet

I would like to implement/use (if it already exists) an SSO solution for drupal and status.net. Something like AuthDrupal for Mediawiki. A google search did not bring up anything.

When a user signs in on status.net it also does in drupal and vice-versa. It also has to change the status.net register and login links to the corresponding drupal pages

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CAS is a good choice. Drupal and StatusNet have their own CAS Authentication plugin. And you should setup Tomcat for CAS server.

Comment: CAS is the right answer. Sadly I had no access to a CAS Server (shared host)

Comment: Helpful update: the Drupal 7.x CAS module (( https://www.drupal.org/project/cas )) can act as a CAS server, and there is a separate D8 cas_server module (( https://www.drupal.org/project/cas_server )).